# Google map application

Tags: android

I am trying to do a google map related application.While doing that application i got some problems.This is my xml file

```
 < LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:apiKey="0uw2roKAecBgrtyYUPVL-pJ84Ez4tfHTilFZCGw"/>
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    /> 
  </LinearLayout>
```

And this is my .java file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {


    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
              LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
              View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();
              zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
              new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
}
```

I am getting google map view for this application but no zoom.
If i change first  to  i am getting output with zoom options..what is the problem with the linear layout.Pls tell me friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing Change your outermost layout to Relative as I thought you want to use.
The problem with LinearLayout is that you forgot to place the weight.
Give the`android:layout_weight="1"` to mapview and `android:layout_weight="0"` to zooom control layout.

Answer (score 0):

to control zoom, panning and other actions you need to define

```
MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in onCreate:

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```